# What is the equivalent of view.postDelayed(Runnable action, long delayMillis) in harmonyos?

Tags: java, android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, harmonyos

I am creating a custom component in HarmonyOS using Java SDK, Where I have to perform some task after some delay with Component instance.

In Android, we have `postDelayed(Runnable action, long delayMillis)` method in **View** class. So we can achieve above requirement as follow

```
view.postDelayed(runnable, 100);
```

but, In HMOS java SDK, I seen there is no any api available for delay in **Component** class.

So, My question is

**What is the equivalent of view.postDelayed(Runnable action, long delayMillis) in harmonyos ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

currently **HarmonyOS** doesn't provide exact alternative for **View.postDelayed(..)** , Instead you can achieve similar UI post functionality using **ohos.eventhandler.EventHandler** API, Sample Usage is as follows

```java
 EventHanlder eventhandler = new EventHandlder(EventRunner.getMainEventRunner());
 eventhandler.postTask(runnable, timeInMillis);
```

Comment: **note:** If you create EventRunner instance like this way `EventRunner eventRunner = EventRunner.create();` then, your app will crashed with **Attempt to update UI in non-UI thread** error. So please do it carefully. May be this comment helpful for others.

Comment: How to do that in smart devices, so JS not Java?

Answer (score 2):

You could also refer to the following code:

```
getUITaskDispatcher().delayDispatch(new Runnable() {

    @Override

    public void run() {

        // Here's the task you want to delay.

    }

}, 100);
```